# How to generate fully coloured electrostatic potential maps in Avogadro?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I want to generate electrostatic potential maps of molecules using Avogadro, that show the colour scheme ranging from blue through green and yellow to red.

In [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khr4mp7HiuQ), at 1:32, the video author does just that.

[image: Youtube video grab showing coloured ESP map]

However, when I try the same thing on my Avogadro (version 1.2.0), it shows this:

[image: My own Avogadro's Screen Capture]

How do i display the colourful electrostatic potential map on my computer? My computer has a 4 GB RAM and an NVIDIA GeForce 210 Graphics Card.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ask the [Avogadro support forum](http://discuss.avogadro.cc/)? That seems a more appropriate venue for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that the color scheme changed, due to user (and developer) feedback. More people preferred the red to white to blue scheme for electrostatics.

In Avogadro 2, we hope to have a full-featured gradient editor, allowing you to set the colors you wish.

Comment: 5 months since this post and situation seems the same

Comment: @TonyM - as indicated in the comment above, there's a support forum for Avogadro and you can post requests on [GitHub](http://github.com/cryos/avogadro/issues/) - while I use Chem.SE, it's no substitute for a GitHub issue tracker.